# Create a SASS mixin for animation

Tags: sass

I want to create a mixin that allows to adjust for percentage on the fly.  I'm getting a bit tripped up, would love some pointers.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
   @keyframes slide-1 {
    0%   {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
    50%  { }
    100% {transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);}
}

@keyframes slide-2 {
    0%   {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
    50%  { }
    100% {transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);}
}
```

Mixin would take an argument of percentage - and I'm assuming the animation name? Something like:

```
@keyframes $animation-name {
    0%   {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
    50%  { }
    100% {transform: translate3d($percentage, 0, 0);}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add mixin somewhere in the top of .sass file just before it is been called. Or you can include it from the external file.

```
@mixin animation-mixin($name, $from, $to) {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    0% {transform: translate3d($from, 0, 0); opacity: 0;}
    100% {transform: translate3d($to, 0, 0); opacity: 1;}
  }
}
```

Call the mixin and pass these 3 values `$name`, `$from`, `$to` like this:

```
@include animation-mixin(slide-1, 0, 100%);
@include animation-mixin(slide-2, 0, 200%);
```

And it would be translated into this:

```
@keyframes slide-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

---

**DEMO**

HTML

```
<div class="box-1"></div>
<div class="box-2"></div>
```

SASS

```
.box-1,
.box-2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box-1 {
  background-color: blue;
  animation: slide-1 2s ease infinite;
}
.box-2 {
  background-color: red;
  animation: slide-2 2s ease infinite;
}

@mixin animation-mixin($name, $from, $to) {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    0% {transform: translate3d($from, 0, 0); opacity: 0;}
    100% {transform: translate3d($to, 0, 0); opacity: 1;}
  }
}

@include animation-mixin(slide-1, 0, 100%);
@include animation-mixin(slide-2, 0, 200%);
```

Comment: CodePen with this answer: https://codepen.io/Hakeemmidan/pen/OJPaezR

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general example how to use it:
In you sass file use **mixing** to add any type of keyframe:

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Then you can declare the animation you want like this:

```
@include keyframes(animate-preloader) {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

And use it to animate you html element like this:

```
#yourElement{
    ...
    animation: animate-preloader 1s linear infinite;
}
```

This allow you to avoid repeat code.